# remove all characters after last occurence of a pattern

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm parsing a txt file such as :

```
>scaffold_1:52559-5269(+):mus_musculus:15-207(+)
AAAGAAAATAATAAAGAAA
>scaffold_2:27092-2200(+):mus_musculus:0-105(+)
AAAGAAAATAAT
```

and the idea is to remove all part after the last : occurrence and get :

```
>scaffold_1:52559-5269(+):mus_musculus
AAAGAAAATAATAAA
>scaffold_2:27092-2200(+):mus_musculus
AAAGAAAATAAT
```

I know the sed command but not for the last occurence. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another `cut` based:

```
$ cut -d : -f -3 file
```

Output:

```
>scaffold_1:52559-5269(+):mus_musculus
AAAGAAAATAATAAAGAAA
>scaffold_2:27092-2200(+):mus_musculus
AAAGAAAATAAT
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Replace a colon followed by any number of non-colons.

```
sed 's/:[^:]*$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

A cut based solution :

```
while read line
do 
  echo "$line" | rev | cut -d: -f2- | rev 
done < file.txt
```